# Set httpOnly and secure flag for AWS ALB cookies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

How can I set these flags to true for AWSALBTG & AWSALBTGCORS cookies?

Comment: Update the ALB Listener:
Under the "Listeners" tab, ensure that the ALB listener is using HTTPS. The Secure attribute requires that the listener uses HTTPS.
Modify the ALB Attributes:
With the ALB selected, click "Description" tab and scroll down to the "Attributes" section. Enable "Stickiness". This allow you to utilize AWSALBTG & AWSALBTGCORS stickiness cookies. The HttpOnly and Secure flags will be set by AWS automatically for these cookies when you enable stickiness with an HTTPS listener.
Verify: tools like curl to ensure that the HttpOnly and Secure flags are set for the ALB cookies.